# 7-Segment, 3-digit display not displaying correctly

Tags: arduino-uno, display, 7-segment

I have written the code that should work, but for some reason the numbers do not display correctly. When I choose to display 3 times the same number it works correctly (so pin connections are correct) but when trying to display different numbers on each digit things get messy. Can anyone see what is wrong with the code? I don't seem to find it. thanks!

Working when 3 digits are the same:

[image: a busy cat]

Not working with different numbers (should be 3, 2, 1:

[image: a busy cat]

And the code:

```
int a = 2;               //Defining segments corresponding to the pins
int b = 3;
int c = 4;
int d = 5;
int e = 6;
int f = 7;
int g = 8;

void setup(void) {      //Setting Pins as output
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(c, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(d, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(e, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(f, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(g, OUTPUT);
}

void WriteNum(int PositionN, int Number) {
  int Position;
  int NumberSegments[10][7] = {{a,b,c,d,e,g},     //Defining segments for forming numbers
                          {b,c},
                          {a,b,d,e,g},
                          {a,b,c,d,g},
                          {b,c,f,d},
                          {a,c,d,f,g},
                          {a,c,d,e,f,g},
                          {a,b,c},
                          {a,b,c,d,e,f,g},
                          {a,b,c,d,f,g}};
  digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);                       //Setting begin conditions (All segments low and no digits turned on)
  digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);

  switch (PositionN) {                        //Deciding which digit to turn on
    case 1:
      Position = A0;
      break;
    case 2:
      Position = A1;
      break;
    case 3:
      Position = A2;
      break;
  }
  digitalWrite(Position, LOW);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(NumberSegments[Number]); i++){       //For each segment in number to display
        digitalWrite(NumberSegments[Number][i], HIGH);            //Light that segment
        }
  delay(5);
}

void loop(void) {
  WriteNum(1,2);
  WriteNum(2,2);
  WriteNum(3,2);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(NumberSegments[Number]` is 14 (as an `int` is two bytes; 2*7=14). The least you should do is use `sizeof(NumberSegments[0]/sizeof(NumberSegments[0][0]`. Since you declare the sub-arrays to be of 7 integers, `{b,c},` will actually be interpreted as `{b,c,0,0,0,0,0},`. So your code is also setting pin 0 to HIGH. Not sure if this have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: That was indeed the problem thanks! Because the sizeof() = 14, it will continue reading the next item in the list and light those segments as well. Setting pin 0 high did not appear to cause any problems but I filled the remaining spaces in the list with copies of an already lit segment anyway. I still wonder why this did not cause problems when the three digits were the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three recommendations for you. @Gerben was correct as to your problem, but doing the following three steps will improve the speed of your code:

1. Change your definition for `NumberSegments` to be `[10][8]`, and put the number of active segments as the first number of each array:

   ```
    ...[10][8] = {{6,a,b,c,d,e,g},     // ...
                  {2,b,c},
                  {5,a,b,d,e,g}, // etcetera
   ```
2. Change your `for` loop as follows:

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= NumberSegments[Number][0]; i++) { // ...
      digitalWrite(NumberSegments[Number][i], HIGH); // ...
   }
   ```

   This will only turn on the minimum number of segments required. Note the loop now starts at `1`, and uses `<=` instead of `<`.
3. Put the keyword `static` in front of `NumberSegments`:

   ```
   static int NumberSegments[10][8] = {{ // ...
   ```

This last one is a language nicety. Every time the function `WriteNum` is called, the poor thing has to re-create the (large) `NumberSegments` array - and it’s the same every time! The keyword `static` means “only create this variable once”. Next time into the function, it’ll already be available: no processing required!

You might also consider moving `int position;` below `NumberSegments`, since it’s convention to put `static` variables first in a function.

You can also use the keyword `const` on `NumberSegments`, since its values never change:

```
static const int NumberSegments[10][8] = {{ // ...
```

Comment: Thanks John! Much appreciated. Looks way more efficient indeed. I believe I'm getting the hang of it